# Align divs horizontally not working

Tags: css, html

So I have two divs that contain text and I want to have them horizontally. I tried using the property `display: inline-block` but it doesn't seem to work.
Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heba0/w4Lb64oq/3/) of my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to use is a `ul` instead of divs and that will allow you to have them all on the same line, if thats what you meant?

```css
.row{
   list-style: none;
}

.row li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="row">
     <li>A108 Adam Street</li>
     <li>New York, NY 535022</li>
     <li>info@exmaple.com</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying for:

```css
.text{
 
  display: inline-block
}

.text1{
   float: left;  
}

.text2{
   float: right;  
}
```

```html
 <div >
              <div class="ion-ios-location-outline text text1">
                <i><p>A108 Adam Street<br>New York, NY 535022</p></i>
              </div>

              <div class="ion-ios-email-outline text text2">
                <i><p>info@example.com</p></i>
              </div>

            </div>
```

If correct, you can reply for further explaination

Answer (score 0):

Default of div is display: block; it makes the div get full width of page. So if you want to make 2 divs stay horizontally. You should set display of div to inline-block;

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.text{

  display: inline-block
}

.text1{
   float: left;  
}

.text2{
   float: right;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the parent div a class and apply **`text-align:center`** property

```css
.parent{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
 <div class='parent'>
              <div  >
                <i class="ion-ios-location-outline "></i>
                <p>A108 Adam Street<br>New York, NY 535022</p>
              </div>

              <div>
                <i class="ion-ios-email-outlinetext " ></i>
                <p>info@example.com</p>
              </div>

          

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of `float` Property :

```css
.text {
  display: inline-block
}

.text1 {
  float: left;  
}

.text2 {
  float: right;  
}

div div:last-child { 
  float:right;
}

div div:first-child {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div >
    <div>
        <i class="ion-ios-location-outline text text1"></i>
        <p>A108 Adam Street<br>New York, NY 535022</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <i class="ion-ios-email-outlinetext text2" ></i>
        <p>info@example.com</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A div by default has its display attribute set to "block". So even if you are setting the display property of of its child  tag, to "inline-block", that would not work.

Setting the parent divs to "inline-block" instead is probably what you need.

Here is the code for your reference (You do not need text, text1 and text2 classes. I've named the class you require as "display-inline-block")

```
            <div>
                <div class="display-inline-block">
                    <i class="ion-ios-location-outline"></i>
                    <p>A108 Adam Street<br>New York, NY 535022</p>
                </div>

                <div class="display-inline-block">
                    <i class="ion-ios-email-outline"></i>
                    <p>info@example.com</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the following css

```
.display-inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

P.S. You can also use the bootstrap css class "d-inline-block" instead, if you are using bootstrap in your project, rather than defining the custom class "display-inline-block".